# R prod() function but in SQL, how to take product of a group by

Tags: r, postgresql, sum, amazon-redshift, dbplyr

In R, taking the product of a group by can be undertaken like:

```
 iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(new_col = prod(Petal.Length))
```

How can I achieve that same concept in either postgresql or dbplyr/dplyr?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. Not all SQL persons do speak R fluently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the SQL standard does not define an aggregate "product" function. You can, however, work around this with arithmetics.

Say that you want to compute the product of `petal_length` in groups of rows sharing the same `species` in table `mytable`:

```
select species, exp(sum(ln(petal_length))) petal_length_product
from mytable
group by species
```

This works as long as all values of `petal_length` are greater than `0`.